# где лучше включать js код

Tags: javascript, html, html5, code-style

здравствуйте подскажите где лучше подключать js файлы в html странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Синтаксис**

```
<script type="тип">
  ...
</script> 
<script type="тип" src="URL"></script>
```

**Атрибуты**
*`async`* - Загружает скрипт асинхронно.
*`defer`* - Откладывает выполнение скрипта до тех пор, пока вся страница не будет загружена полностью.
*language* - Устанавливает язык программирования на котором написан скрипт.
*`src`* - Адрес скрипта из внешнего файла для импорта в текущий документ.
*`type`* - Определяет тип содержимого тега .
**Закрывающий тег**
Обязателен.

хочется сказать что можно и в начале но тогда надо включать проверку на загрузку `DOM`

```
window.onload = function(){}
```

либо

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

в зависимости от логики но я подключаю перед `</body>`

вот еще стоит обратить внимание

Атрибут **async**

> Поддерживается всеми браузерами, кроме IE9-. Скрипт выполняется
>   полностью асинхронно. То есть, при обнаружении  браузер не останавливает обработку страницы, а спокойно
>   работает дальше. Когда скрипт будет загружен – он выполнится.

Атрибут **defer**

> Поддерживается всеми браузерами, включая самые старые IE. Скрипт также
>   выполняется асинхронно, не заставляет ждать страницу, но есть два
>   отличия от async.

Первое – браузер гарантирует, что относительный порядок скриптов с defer будет сохранён.

То есть, в таком коде (с async) первым сработает тот скрипт, который раньше загрузится:

примеры

```
<script src="1.js" async></script>
<script src="2.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Стоит сказать, что их можно ставить оба сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший вариант подключать **некоторые** скрипты в конце.
Зачем? Те, что подключаются снизу будут выполнятся как загрузится код HTML.
 Если они будут в теге <head> они выполнятся раньше.

Например, можно вверху страницы подключать библиотеки, а снизу скрипты, код, который будет связан с библиотеками.